# ng-repeat binding element array multiple times

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a dictionary of 3 elements, when i try to bind using ng-repeat, each dictionary element is getting bound 3 times. When the number of elements increase to 4, then each dictionary element is getting bound 4 times.

```
<ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="(m, v) in vm.test track by $index">
                            <span>{{m}}:{{v}}</span>
                        </li>
 </ul>
```

vm.test contains- {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

Can anyone help me find what is the issue here?
i am using this in a angular directive.

Question Updated**

when i get html content i see that ng-repeat is present twice:

```
<ul>
                   <!-- ngRepeat: (m, v) in vm.test track by $index --><li ng-repeat="(m, v) in vm.test track by $index" class="ng-scope">
                       <span class="ng-binding">a:1</span>
                   </li><!-- end ngRepeat: (m, v) in vm.test track by $index --><li ng-repeat="(m, v) in vm.test track by $index" class="ng-scope">
                       <span class="ng-binding">b:2</span>
                   </li><!-- end ngRepeat: (m, v) in vm.test track by $index --><li ng-repeat="(m, v) in vm.test track by $index" class="ng-scope">
                       <span class="ng-binding">c:3</span>
                   </li><!-- end ngRepeat: (m, v) in vm.test track by $index -->
               </ul>
```

What would be the case where ng-repeat gets added twice?

Comment: what do you mean "bound" multiple times? can you show sample output?

Comment: the dictionary elements {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} appears thrice:
a:1
a:1
a:1
b:2
b:2
b:2
b:2
c:3
c:3
c:3

Comment: No issues here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WSwMMYA7XemXjyMkLMNi?p=preview

Comment: not able to replicate it in plunkr. :(

Comment: So your error exists with something in your local code. :(

Comment: when i get html content i see that ng-repeat is present twice, please see the updated question

Comment: i am not sure if this is the case with me too: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6006
I am as well using ng-repeat within a directive.